# Disable pencil of rowEditor in primeFaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to disable row Editor in some rows(because of their specific data)
I search too much but I can't find a way to do that.

I have two type of rows,rows with status A and rows with status B.

I want to enable pencil for rows A and disable for rows B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can:

```
 <p:column rendered="#{listvar.status != 'B'}">  
                    <p:rowEditor />  
 </p:column>
```

Comment: I try it but this error happened:  Element type "p:column" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>" And my code is :<p:column rendered="#{contract.status !="Done"}">  <p:rowEditor/>                                               </p:column>

Comment: thanks...now it's work.but how can I check two condition like (done or accept)

Comment: You can: rendered="#{contract.status !='Done' or contract.status !='accept'}"

Answer (score 1):

Rong's answer is great, but you will notice that if you render the column your table will miss some lines...

Just put the rendered on the rowEditor to avoid this design issue :

```
    <p:column >  
                    <p:rowEditor rendered="#{listvar.status != 'B'}" />        
</p:column>
```